# Error when trying to build and package net5 global tool using msbuild

Tags: c#, msbuild, .net-5

I have a global tool with target framework net5.0 I can build and package nuget from VS. But it fails when doing the same from msbuild

msbuild project

```
  <Target Name="Build">
    <Exec Command="..\.nuget\nuget.exe restore $(NugetFolder)\SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy.AspNetCore.GlobalTool.csproj" />
    <MSBuild Projects="$(NugetFolder)\SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy.AspNetCore.GlobalTool.csproj" Properties="Configuration=Release;OutDir=$(NugetFolder)\out\"/>
  </Target>
```

Cs proj Im trying to build

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <PackAsTool>true</PackAsTool>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <PackageReleaseNotes>
    </PackageReleaseNotes>
    <Version>5.2.266.0</Version>
    <PackageLicenseExpression>MIT</PackageLicenseExpression>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="SignalR.EventAggregatorProxyCore" Version="5.2.265.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Error message during build

> C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.202\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(241,5):
> error NETSDK1005: Assets file
> 'C:\git\SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy3\NugetOutput\obj\project.assets.json'
> doesn't have a target for 'net5.0'. Ensure that restore has run and
> that you have included 'net5.0' in the TargetFrameworks for your
> project.
> [C:\git\SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy3\NugetOutput\SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy.AspNetCore.GlobalTool.csproj]

**update**
Executing a dotnet build  works, but I dont know if its a preferred way?

```
  <Target Name="Build">
      <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(NugetFolder)" Command="dotnet build --configuration Release" />
  </Target>
```

Comment: Are you sure `SignalR.EventAggregatorProxyCore` version is correct? There is no version like `5.2.265.0` in [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxyCore/)

Comment: Yeah I have a local nuget for testing (Im the author) :)

Comment: If I execute a dotnet build it works. See update